# encrypted database user balance column

Tags: database, asp.net-core, architecture, software-design

In a banking system which pattern is best for encrypted user balance . now we are using AES algorithm to encrypt balance then store in db. but the problem is when we need any report which customer balance is large . we need to get all data from db and application level decrypt the data . 
I need a suggestion which pattern is best for this type of situation